# What size can my checked luggage be on Kuwait Airways?

Tags: air-travel, legal, luggage

It says on Kuwait Airways website that 3 dimensions shall not exceed 158 cm. Does this mean the length, width and depth can be any size, just that they need to all add up to 158cm?

I have never been abroad so I'm new to this.

Answer (score 6):

It simply means:

```
Length + Height + width
```

[image: luggage]

The total of that should not exceed the allowed size. In your case it is 158 cm. BTW that's called *linear length*.

Comment: Welcomt to travel.SE. If you think this is the right answer, please click on the tick next to it to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

As noted [on their website](http://www.kuwaitairways.com/Default.aspx?pageId=36):

> the total sum of the 3 dimensions (Width + length + height) shall not exceed 158 cm (62") for each bag piece.

Additionally, for economy class passengers, the total linear dimensions of two pieces of checked baggage shall not exceed 273 cm (107"), so if your first bag measures 158 linear cm, the second one cannot exceed 115 cm.

There are no limits on any single dimension, so if you had an unusually tall bag it should be fine provided it is shorter or shallower to make up for it.

Note that [dimension limits](http://www.kuwaitairways.com/Default.aspx?pageId=35) do apply for cabin luggage:

> The maximum size is usually 23 x 36 x 56 cm (115 cm total) or 9 x 14 x 22" (45" total)

Comment: so it dont matter what size each of the dimensions are as long as all 3 add up to 158cm ?

Comment: As I noted in the answer, there are no limits listed on any single dimension. Provided the sum of the dimensions is under 158 cm, Kuwait Airways should allow you to check the bag.

Comment: @choster your second quoted example has x rather than + suggesting the total is a volume rather than a linear length is this a typo or am I miss understanding something?

Comment: @Stuart It's a direct quote from the airline's web page. I think it's just a conventional way of expressing the dimensions, since each individual dimension is indeed limited for carryons.

Comment: @choster ok makes sense